# Python serial.read() split error

Tags: python

I have an Arduino connected to my PC. The Arduino sends this over serial:
`xx,yyy\n` and I want to split it into two variables ... xx to tep and yyy to tlak, so I have written the following but it is giving me an error:

```
print("A list of the serial ports available on the system:")
print(serial_ports())
port = "COM" + input("Please enter the port number...")
# Setup
ser = serial.Serial(port, 9600, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)

while True:
    sercan = ser.read()
    can = sercan.decode("utf-8")
    tep, tlak = can.split(",")
    print("T:", tep, " Tl:", tlak)
    #print(can)
```

And result:

```
tep, tlak = can.split(",")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Have you checked to see what the value of `can` is prior to splitting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in using `sercan = ser.read()` where `read` reads by default only 1 byte according to pySerial documentation.

Workaround is to read until '\n' is received or to use `readline` or to specify number of bytes to read.

Comment: Not working :( ...
This is a raw data from sercan:
b'25,976\n'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\n'